# Chrome won't play WebAudio getUserMedia via WebRTC/Peer.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, peerjs

I want to make a simple audio only stream over WebRTC, using [Peer.js](http://peerjs.com/). I'm running the simple PeerServer locally.

The following works perfectly fine in Firefox 30, but I can't get it to work in **Chrome 35**. I would expect there was something wrong with the PeerJS setup, but Chrome -> Firefox works perfectly fine, while Chrome -> Chrome seems to send the stream, but won't play over speakers.

**Setting up getUserMedia** *Note: uncommenting those lines below will let me hear the loopback in Chrome and Firefox.*

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}, getMediaSuccess, getMediaError);
} else {
    alert('getUserMedia not supported.');
}

var localMediaStream;
//var audioContext = new AudioContext();

function getMediaSuccess(mediaStream) {
    //var microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
    //microphone.connect(audioContext.destination);
    localMediaStream = mediaStream;
}

function getMediaError(err) {
    alert('getUserMedia error. See console.');
    console.error(err);
}
```

**Making the connection**

```
var peer = new Peer({host: '192.168.1.129', port: 9000});

peer.on('open', function(id) {
    console.log('My ID:', id);
});

peer.on('call', function(call) {
    console.log('answering call with', localMediaStream);
    call.answer(localMediaStream);
    //THIS WORKS IN CHROME, localMediaStream exists

    call.on('stream', function(stream) {
        console.log('streamRecieved', stream);
        //THIS WORKS IN CHROME, the stream has come through

        var audioContext = new AudioContext();
        var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        audioStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
        //I HEAR AUDIO IN FIREFOX, BUT NOT CHROME

    });

    call.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        //LOGS NO ERRORS
    });
});

function connect(id) {
    var voiceStream = peer.call(id, localMediaStream);
}
```

Comment: what if you change `AudioContext()` to `webkitAudioContext()`? Just a shot in the dark as there should not really be a difference.

Comment: tried it, no difference. I think line 2 in the first section would have taken care of that anyways.

Comment: You're right...this is an interesting predicament.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chrome, it is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=121673&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=121673) currently where remote audio streams gathered from a peer connection are not accessible through the AudioAPI.

Latest comment on the bug:

> We are working really hard towards the feature. The reason why this
>   takes long time is that we need to move the APM to chrome first,
>   implement a render mixer to get the unmixed data from WebRtc, then we
>   can hook up the remote audio stream to webaudio.

It was recently patched in Firefox as I remember this being an issue on there as well in the past.

Comment: Half a year past, still failed on Chrome M40

Comment: @Imskull, that sucks. Just checked the bug report and Justin Uberti says that they are only about a quarter of the way done and the team that has been working on it/will fix it are pulled away to other issues currently. From what I have read, it is a pretty serious design flaw and not just a coding bug.

Comment: yes, it seems weird that google advocates webrtc everywhere w/o gets this issue to be fixed for 3 years. there are something under the hood.

Comment: [solved](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121673#c96) in Chrome Canary during December 2015

Answer (score 10):

This still appears to be an issue even in Chrome 73.

The solution that saved me for now is to also connect the media stream to a muted HTML audio element. This seems to make the stream work and audio starts flowing into the WebAudio nodes.

This would look something like:

```
let a = new Audio();
a.muted = true;
a.srcObject = stream;
a.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
    a = null;
});

let audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
audioStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmcker/4naq5ozc/

---

Original Chromium issue and workaround: 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121673#c121

New Chromium issue: <strike>https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687574</strike> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677

Comment: This answer is definitely hacky, but completely harmless if the Chrome team ever does fix the issue. Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: The Chrome issue for this is [Issue 933677: MediaStream from RTC is silent for Web Audio API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677). [#687574 AEC when using Web Audio API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=687574) is about microphone echo cancellation not working when using Web Audio API (it only works with WebRTC, because AEC is implemented in libwebrtc).

Comment: Wow. This still requires the workaround in Chrome 105.

Comment: March 2023, still here

Comment: Still here in september 2023!

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to play the stream using web audio but I did manage to play it uses a basic audio element:

```
 var audio = new Audio();                                                  
 audio.src = (URL || webkitURL || mozURL).createObjectURL(remoteStream);
 audio.play();
```