# Is it possible to manipulate the audio from an RTCTrackEvent using the Web Audio API in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I can successfully add a gain node to an audio element sourced from a file, but when I try it with a stream / audio element derived from an RTCTrackEvent's audio stream it ignores the gain node. I was curious if this was possible at all.

Comment: It has come to my attention that my issue is from a Chrome bug, modifying question to make it clearer for people searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known bug in Chrome that causes the stream not to work unless you do a hack and include a muted audio element. See the answer by jmcker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287054/chrome-wont-play-webaudio-getusermedia-via-webrtc-peer-js) for the method and a jsfiddle example. This solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Checkout this sample - https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/webaudio-input/

Source code - https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/webaudio-input