# Why does Chrome not output WebRTC audio with AudioContext?

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, html5-audio, audiocontext

I'm implementing a WebRTC Audio chat. I have everything working, and was initially using `<audio>` elements to output the audio, which worked fine.

But then I wanted to implement a "Speaking indicator" feature, and decided to go with AudioContext.

It works, in Safari + Firefox, but no Chrome. I just don't get any output.

This is my code:

```js
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

// Create an audio source node from the stream received by the
// RTCPeerConnection with peerConnection.ontrack()
const audioSourceNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

// Connect the audio source to the destination
audioSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to somehow use an `<audio>` element to get sound on Chrome?

Comment: you might have blocked microphone on your browser

Comment: As I said, using an <audio> element works fine. And chrome has the issue outputting the audio all others can output it fine, so it can't be a mic permission problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677) in Chrome that wasn't fixed so far.

A common workaround is to create a muted `<audio>` element to make the audio flowing (it can be deleted after). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644983/4755595) for an example.